# PHP MySQL: GET new way to query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a question game quiz in my SQL query as

- question 1 to 10
- I use sql random query to select question
- use array push to keep previous question
- use sql query [query from array push] to select new question (no more previous question show up)

**FIRST QUESTION START**

- 1: `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE catid="9" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1`
- 2: SQL query get id=2 so array push = `(2)`

**SECOND QUESTION START (if answer correct)**

- 1: `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE catid="9" AND ( id <> "2" ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1`
- 2: SQL query get id=5 so array push = `(2,5)`

**THIRD QUESTION START (if answer correct)**

- 1: `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE catid="9" AND ( id <> "2" AND id <> "5" ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1`
- 2: SQL query get id=1 so array push = `(2,5,1)`

  **... QUESTION START (if answer correct)**
- 1: ....
- 2: ....

So I just want to know if I have 1000 questions so my SQL query going to:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE catid="9" AND ( id <> "2" AND id <> "5" AND id <> "1" AND .... AND id <> "999" ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This should be slow for page process or not?.

If slow, should we have another way to process this query? thanks....

Comment: I don't think it is slowing the page that much... I thought you have a problem and not just asking for opinion. My bad.

Comment: First of all, change this: id <> 2 and id <> 5 and... to this: id NOT IN (2,5,1...) and you can store them as an array and check against it.

Comment: 1000 is really not that much in database terms. 100 000, still not that much. Maybe a bigger concern would be getting query size limits errors with this approach. However doing something akin to this is probably unavoidable based on your requirements (unless you're willing to create a temporary table for each user that keeps track on unasked questions only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the id of the previous question to an array.

```
$array[] = $previous_id;
```

Select a random question with id not in `$array`.

```
$ids = join(',',$array);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE catid="9" AND id NOT IN ($ids) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Repeat this process while the answer is correct.

**edit :** Also, you should properly sanitize the inputs to prevent `SQL injection`

Comment: NOT IN ($array) should be NOT IN ($ids)

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the entire array of questions at the start, and choosing a random question from that (using a random number times the length of the array) and after asking it - either just remove it from the array or move it to a different array - maybe"questionsAsked" or something?that way you do not need to continually keep adding to the list of exclusions - you simply select from the remaining questions? and the questionsAsked array keeps the list of the asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but you can use `DISTINCT` to query different values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, catid, ... FROM questions WHERE catid="9" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```